# How to assign list created inside a function to the data frame column

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, global-variables, python-tesseract

I am using python 3.7.4 on VS code. I created a function `img_to_text()` which takes argument as a pdf file. This function creates JPEG of the first page of the PDF and use `pytesseract.image_to_string()` method to read string from the image. This string is then searched for some names and if a name appear in the string, it's then appended to the list `main_consultant_name()`.

Since the run time for the whole process was considerably high, I used multiprocessing to reduce the run time which was indeed reduced to 2 minutes from the sequential runtime of 34 minutes for 258 PDFs

```
def img_to_text(file):
    main_consultant_name = []
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\.....\......\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    pages = convert_from_path("C:/pdfs" + file + '.pdf', 500, last_page= 1)
    for page in pages:
        filename = file +'_Page1.jpg'
        page.save("C:/Users/................" + filename, 'JPEG')
        text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("C:/Users/............../" + filename))))).lower().replace('\n\n',' ')
        consultant_name = []
        for name in consultant_name_lst:
            if name.lower() in text:
                consultant_name.append(name)
        main_consultant_name.append(consultant_name)
    return main_consultant_name

def process_handler():
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        query1 = "SELECT * FROM pdfs;"
        df1 = pd.read_sql(query1, conn)
    files = [file for file in df1['pdfName']]
    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(img_to_text, files)
    for result in results:
        print(result)

df1['consultant_name'] = main_consultant_name     # problem is here
```

I am trying to add a column in dataframe `df1` from list `main_consultant_name`, but I get an error message `NameError: name 'main_consultant_name' is not defined`. I did some research and kind of got some idea that since list has been defined inside the function, it cannot be accessed outside of the function. I tried to globally define the list but it did not work and returned the same error message.

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the explanation is because the concept of `namespaces` and `variable scope`, there are always three `namespaces` which are `Built-in`, `global` and `local` and sometimes there is one more called `Enclosing`. In short, the variables declared in the module belongs to `global namespace` and the variables declared in a function belongs to `local` and you can access from `local` to `global` as below:

```
a = 'Hello'
def testing():
  return a

print(testing()) # Prints 'Hello'
```

But you can't access from `global`  to `local` and it's what you're trying to do in your code, just to show you with same before example:

```
def testing():
  a = 'Hello'
  return a

print(a)
```

Raises the error: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

So what you can do is catching what `img_to_text` returns and then assign to `df1['consultant_name']`:

```
def testing():
  a = 'Hello'
  return a

result = testing()
print(result) # Prints 'Hello'
```

Or something like this using `global` but it's not recommended :

```
a = ''
def testing():
  global a
  a = 'Hello'
  return a

result = testing()
print(result)
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It worked and I have tweaked my code a bit. Now I have created 5 functions and I am calling each function in the subsequent functions. Then the last function is being called under `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Do you think this is the correct pythonic approach? Thanks once again!

Comment: Fellow, gives it some love with an up vote at least before asking another question, try to be grateful.

Comment: I am really grateful for your suggestion over the query that I asked Brad. I already up voted your answer but I get this response from stackoverflow whenever I try to up vote anyone's answer  **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**

Answer (score 0):

main_consultant_name is a local variable you create within the img_to_text function which is run in the worker processes in your pool and doesn't exist in your main process. The value you want is results which is a list of all the values returned from the pool. I'm not very familiar with SQLAlchemy which I believe is what you're using to access your database correct? Anyway I don't know if you're adding a column in an appropriate way and I'm also not sure if you just want to add the column to display it or if you want to insert the values into your DB?

Oh also as an aside if you want to speed up your program, if the pdf isn't already flattened as an image you can use something like [PyMupdf](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to isolate the text in the file directly so you don't have to do OCR.

Comment: @ David Thanks for letting me know that there is a functionality in the PyMuPDF package to convert page to image. I was using pdf2image package in my code as of now, however I will definitely give PyMuPDF a try since I am aware that the processing run time is really quick with PyMuPDF

Comment: Hopefully it works out for you. Do keep in mind that the biggest speed up is by isolating the text in the pdf before you convert it to an image which means you shouldn't have to use tesseract at all.